# Odd disconnects with remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I run a Windows Server (2012 R2 Standard) and connect via RDP from Windows 7 (x64). Within my RDP session, I run an application that, from time to time, plays a sound and also shows a wall clock.

When I work locally on Win7 (e.g. doing mails) the RDP client is neither minimized nor fullscreen, i.e. a regular window and after a while I get behavior below reported.

When I bring the RDP client to front (i.e. because the remote application played a sound and I want to check) I can see the wall clocks seconds still increasing, but no mouse click or keyboard input is accepted. Roughly 10 seconds later the RDP session blacks out, shows the reconnect window, reconnects and I can continue to work.

Normally I'd guess that I got disconnected due to inactivity, but getting sound played and seeing the clock work (seconds still increase), tells me that the underlying TCP-connection still works. It seems I only get disconnected after sending some input (keyboard or mouse).

So I don't really understand what's going on (is this expected behavior?), nor what I could do, to prevent these reconnects?

Comment: How does your Win 7 machine connect to the remote server? Locally, over the Internet? Also, try running a continuous ping to the remote server with `ping -t servername` and observe if there is any packet loss around the time you experience the black out.

Comment: @Twisty: I connect via Internet and no, I don't see packet losses when running the ping command in the background.